# Input's position won't budge

Tags: css

I am trying to move a input element is a way that it won't escape the "popUp"  (div) I created to contain it and to center it, but no matter what I do it won't move.

I have to say it is rather annoying.

I prepared a fiddle to further illustrate the point, also this is the input I am talking about:

```
  <div class="popUp " id="popUpCorrecto1">
 <div class="estiloPopUp">
    <span>Carga Masiva</span>
    <span value="Cerrar" id="btnCerrar">x</span>
 </div>
 <p>Seleccione un archivo de tipo CSV. El archivo no debe excedar los 100KB.</p>

       <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploader.php" method="post" id="uploadForm">
          <input name="csvUpload" id="upload" type="file" accept=".csv" class="left" />
       </form>

</div>

http://jsfiddle.net/WKkL5/
```

Honestly I almost threw my laptop out of the window, any help would be very appreciated.

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/WKkL5/)

Comment: You can add `overflow-x:hidden` to `.popUp`.

Comment: @Vucko bad option, its just that the positioning has gone really weird

Comment: Where do you want to place that input?

Comment: @Mr.Alien it seems the only option if he wants to keep his current styles. His whole layout is not really good, but if he wants to center the `input`, I would suggest `#popUpCorrecto1 form{text-align:center}`

Comment: is this what you are trying to achieve? http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/WKkL5/1/

Comment: I am well aware the layout is crap, in my defence it was done by my lazy ass partner for this course and I am pretty sure he did some auto generated shit.

Comment: @web-tiki That was exactly what I need, now I only need to add Vucko´s snippet and I am done. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `position:relative;` on the `<p>` and `<input>` elements to achieve your layout.

I suggest using the default positioning (static) and using margins so you elements don't overlay. Then you can use `text-align:center;` on the form element to center the input.

See this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/WKkL5/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

You should take advantage of the **text-align: center;** and display: **inline-block;** combo to do a center alignment. Also you can use the **margin: 0 auto;** with a fixed width to center block elements.

```
#popUpCorrecto1 p {
    position: relative;
    margin: 40px auto 20px;
    width: 180px;
}
```

Regarding to your problem, there's going to be always troubles centering that particular element since the input file form control depends on the browser it's render on. Eg, in Firefox you'll get a bigger input file control while in IE may be a little one. To avoid this, you can use a css-trick so you can place a custom button instead of the input file.

See my solution here:

http://jsfiddle.net/WKkL5/2/